# How do i Make sure the Api call is made faster and the state is Set instantly using UseEffect()?

Tags: reactjs

So i am making a quiz project where am fetching data from an Api and to store the data from the APi i am using a State , initially am setting the value of state as null and making the API call using useEffect and then the data that is received is set to the value in state.And onclick it should render al the elements

```
const [questions,setQuestions] = React.useState(null)

React.useEffect(() =\> {
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
.then(res =\> res.json())
.then(data =\> setQuestions(
data.results
))
})

function handleClick() {
        setStartGame(false)       
            setQuestionElements(questions.map(question => <Question   key={question.id} data={question} />))
    }
```

am getting the error message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')"
if i start the game, it doesnt happen all the time but only when i start(click the button) too fast

Comment: just add an if(questions)in your handle click because an api call need sometime.

Comment: first, it would cause an infinite re-render with no dep's ... and not sure what do you mean by "fast" it depends on lots of factors .... the data would be available in next render after set, consider a loading state ...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent such an error, you can add a `null` check in your handler.

But the rule of thumb is to show a loader and not show the startGame button while your request is not resolved.

```
const Quiz = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [isStarted, switchGameState] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setQuestions(data.results);
            setLoading(false)
        })
  })

  function handleClick() {
    // ....
    switchGameState(true);
  }

  if(loading) {
    return 'loading';
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {!isStarted && <button onClick={handleClick}>Start game</button>}
        {isStarted && questions && questions.map(question => <Question  key={question.id} data={question} />)}
    </div>
)
```

}